# Postgresql - problem using json function in nested queries - hstore

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table orders with a field order_detail of type hstore which saves json data.

Now I want to query on the inner objects of my json data. because The query is somehow complicated I'm trying to tell my problem in easier scenario.

I have tested these 4 subqueries:

1. Get the original saved json:

   ```
   select order_detail::json as original
   from orders;
   ```

   This query successfully returns the json formatted data.
2. Get the inner object 'transaction' inside the order_details:

   ```
    select order_detail::json as original,
           (order_detail -> 'transaction')::json as transaction 
    from order_details;
   ```

   This query also works successfully.
3. Get the id of that transaction:

   ```
    select order_detail::json as original,
          (order_detail -> 'transaction')::json as transaction, 
          ((order_detail -> 'transaction')::json -> 'id')::text as id
    from order_details;
   ```

   The above also works successfully and returns the original json, transaction and id inside the transaction.
4. Select based on the result of query 3 and get one of the results:

   ```
    select original 
    from 
        (select order_detail::json as original,
                (order_detail -> 'transaction')::json as transaction,
                ((order_detail -> 'transaction')::json -> 'id')::text as id 
         from order_details) s
    where transaction is null and id is null;
   ```

   This query will raise an exception! The exception says that:

   > [22P02] ERROR there is a token '=' is invalid**

   Why does this exception occurs only in the **4th** query? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Does it work if you use `hstore_to_json()` instead of casting?

Comment: "*of type hstore which saves json data*" - that doesn't make sense it's either hstore or JSON. Why isn't that a `jsonb` or at least a `json` column if you need the data as JSON?

Comment: thanks for your answer @a_horse_with_no_name . Actually the database in not mine. I'm just trying to get some reports out of it and though I can not use another datatype for it.The main question is: why the nested query which is working with json and works successfully(query 3), but when I want to use the result of it in a nested query it will raise exception (query 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem. When you want have such a field which is json stored in hstore, if you use a simple query you can use something like this:

```
order_detail -> 'trasaction'
```

and this will return the transaction part of hashed-stored data in the order_detail field with no problem.

**BUT** if you want to use such thing in a nested query, you **MUST** explicitly declare that the field is json. so you must use something like this instead (in all parts of inner query):

```
order_detail::json -> 'transaction'
```